# Weird positioning and behavior of dialogue

Tags: wxpython

In the example below, 'handler()' is called twice - first as a regular function, and next - optionally - as an event handler.
**My ultimate goal is to make it work as per the former option**, but whatever I do, I run into the following problems:

- The SingleChoiceDialog appears **somewhere** in the top left corner of the screen, instead of centered relative to the frame
- GetStringSelection() outputs not just the selected string, but a second value: 'None'

  ```
  import wx

  def handler(fragment):
      ChoiceOptions=['alpha','beta','gamma']
      dlg = wx.SingleChoiceDialog(frame,"make a choice", 'Caption', ChoiceOptions, wx.CENTRE )        
      if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
          print dlg.GetStringSelection()
          dlg.Destroy()       

  if __name__ =="__main__":
      app = wx.App(False)
      frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "Meaningless")
      btn = wx.Button(frame, label='Get going')
      btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, (lambda stub: handler('must keep this param')))
      frame.Show(True)
      print 'handler returned',handler('must keep this param')
      app.MainLoop()
  ```

When the same function is invoked as an event handler, those problems disappear. I really need to understand how to make them go away at will.

> EDIT: I tried removing and putting back the 'parent' parameter of
>   SingleChoiceDialog, but it didn't change anything at all. I realize
>   that the first problem has something to do with the actual parent of
>   the dialog, but there's nothing I can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out the reason - it's the style flag wx.CENTRE. Any other flag, and the code works as intended. But it's still weird and looks like a bug to me.